# Java NIO Socket inside docker between windows and unix with failed

Tags: sockets, unix, docker, nio

I made NIO socket client and server by [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/java-nio-socket-example/). It works fine on local machine. I deployed `NIO_Server.jar` on docker container with this args on 7878 port:

```
docker run -ti --net=host -v $HOME:/usr/app -w /usr/app --name=test java:7 java -jar NIO_Server.jar
```

and server successful started. Notice, that i set `--net=host`.
With `-p` option same affect. I didn't use `--expose`, because with `-p` ports exposes implicitly.

```
root@bess2:~# docker run -ti --net=host -v $HOME:/usr/app -w /usr/app --name=test java:7 java -jar NIO_Server.jar 
EchoServer started...
```

I wanted to make sure that it is work inside host:

```
root@bess2:~# netstat -antu | grep 7878
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7878          :::*                   LISTEN
root@bess2:~# telnet localhost 7878
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Inside container i see events:

```
EchoServer started...
Something received...
It is acceptable...
Connected to: /127.0.0.1:55974
Something received...
It is readable...
Something received...
It is readable...
```

But on may local machine I try to connect on host server with failure:

> C:\Users\MONSTERMASH>telnet 31.148.99.130 7878 Connecting To
>   31.148.99.130...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7878: Connect failed

but with ping:

```
C:\Users\MONSTERMASH>ping 31.148.99.130

Pinging 31.148.99.130 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 31.148.99.130: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 31.148.99.130: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 31.148.99.130: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=56
Reply from 31.148.99.130: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 31.148.99.130:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 17ms
```

---

This is IP config from host:

```
root@filesbess2:~# ifconfig 
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:81:11:7b:c7
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:81ff:fe11:7bc7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:27254 (27.2 KB)  TX bytes:6704 (6.7 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:97:1e:86
          inet addr:31.148.99.130  Bcast:31.148.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe97:1e86/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:137351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:577681422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10756344 (10.7 MB)  TX bytes:534585313126 (534.5 GB)
```

Firewalls and antiviruses on local machine and host are turn off or inactive. Host Ubuntu 14.04 deploys on KVM. I made this test, with host was been deployed on virtualbox. Issue is same.

Comment: @Dominic Cerisano I resolved issue. Another case like win-win, unix-unix didnt work, too. My be my answer will be not correct, but socket server address should have ip of hardware adapter. `-p` not work, becouse it is bridge. Work with option `docker run --net=host --name=test --rm -v $HOME:/usr/app java:7 java -jar /usr/app/NIO_Server.jar 31.148.99.130 7979`

Answer (score 0):

You should throw a packet sniffer on both environments and look at the NIO payloads.

Linux and Windows libraries can have reversed endianity (little vs big). The handshake may be failing because one is "left-handed", and the other is "right-handed".

Root around in your NIO API for an endian switch. Do an OS check in the client and make sure it's NIO messages are oriented properly for the server.

This is known as an OS "boundary condition", which appear esp. between windows and linux.

Also check the whitespace and padding in the payloads, and make sure the versions of NIO on both environments are compatible.

You might want to use a higher level NIO framework (eg. Netty) which handle many boundary conditions under the hood, like browsers do.